# Using 'if' statements inside a variable

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, if-statement

I've got the coding below where I use an `if` statement.

```
var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
{
    SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Longitudinals" && x.Section == TruckSection.FloorSpecification).First(),
    //If statement below.
    StockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated" ? db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH095").First() : db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100").First(),
};
```

What I want to know how would I create more than one `if` statement inside the line where I declare the `StockItem`. Or if there is some better way to do this while not using an `if` statement, please let me know :)

Thank you!

Comment: _"I use an if statement."_ you use the conditional operator not an `if`- statement. Apart from that, why can't you use `&&`, so `Name == "Insulated" && otherCondition`?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - Thanks for the comment. As I said, I'm not very good at c# and is still very new to everything, but thank you for the advice! :)

Comment: For the sake of the next person to come along, if the initialization is potentially that complex split it out into a separate function.

Comment: Please can you post 'psudo' code of what you would want the if statement to be?

Comment: You can create an extension method for your StockItem class (In which you can put your if/else blocks) and call the ExtensionMethod then.

Comment: "not very good at C#" yet you wrote a LINQ query with the conditional operator!? I'm boggled. Anyway, some easy beginner reading here that shows you how to use multiple conditions http://www.tradingcode.net/csharp/operators/conditional-operator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to chain ?: calls like this

```
predicateA ? expressionA : predicateB ? expressionB : expressionC
```

This would be equivalent to

```
if (predicateA)
{
    expressionA
}
else if (predicateB)
{
    expressionB
}
else expressionC
```

I would however recommend you to refactor your code a bit. Something like this maybe?

```
var stockCode = quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated" ? "SCH095" : "SCH100";

...

    StockItem = db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == stockCode).First();
```

And then go from there.

Answer (score 2):

I think the better way would be

```
string Condition(string cond) 
{
    switch(cond)
    {
        case "Insulated":
            return "SCH095";
           ...
    }
}
StockItem = db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == Condition(quoteItem.BodyType.Name)).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Like that

```
        StockItem = (quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated"
                         ? db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH095").First()
                         : (condition
                                ? db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100").First()
                                : (nextcondition
                                       ? true
                                       : false)));
```

and so on.
But i dont think this is good style. The readability for others and for you in some months will not be increased ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Ternary Operator`. And **Yes** you can add as many conditions as you want but it will be a Bad Programming Practice. Use `if` statements for multiple conditions. 
[Explanation of Ternary Operators](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ternary) 
[Explanation of if statments](http://www.dotnetperls.com/if)

**Demo 1** (Using Ternary Operators) :

```
StockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated" ?
                          db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH095").First() : 
                         ( quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Promoted"?
                                        db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100").First():
                                        db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH148").First());
```

**Demo 2** (Using If Statement):

```
StockItem stockItem=null;
if(quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated")
{
   stockItem = b.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH095").First();
}
else if(quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Promoted")
{
   stockItem = b.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100").First();   
}
else
{
   stockItem = b.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH148").First();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called a ternary operator. You can simply define other conditions in extra code paths as long as you keep the `? :` syntax consistent within each branch. Now, I wouldn't recommend this as it sounds like a case for a `switch` block, but there you go.

Comment: In C# it's called `Conditional Operator` and not ternary operator.

Comment: It's called the conditional operator, although it is a ternary operator (it has three operands).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested conditional operator for that purpose if you really want to keep it in the line which I do not recommend for readability.

Please refer to the link for the use of the nested conditional operator.

http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post5273_how-to-read-nested-ternary-operators

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for multiple conditions, instead of:

```
StockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated" ? 
                db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH095").First() 
                : db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100").First()
```

Use it like this:

```
StockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "Insulated" ? 
                db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH095").First() 
                : ( quoteItem.BodyType.Name == "unInsulated" ) ?
                          db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH995").First() 
                          : db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH110").First()
```

You can concatenate any number of conditions but this is not a good idea as readability of the code suffers.